# when home button pressed view origin changed?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios9, statusbar

I have this code in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    //we need to add white background behind the status bar
    CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    UIView* statusBarWhiteBackGround = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
    [statusBarWhiteBackGround setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:statusBarWhiteBackGround];

    UIView * redBackGroundColor  = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [redBackGroundColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    redBackGroundColor.frame =CGRectMake(0,statusBarHeight , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-statusBarHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:redBackGroundColor];
```

statusWhiteBackGround view is used to change the color of the status bar.
here is the result of the above code:

[image]

but when the app enter background and then back to foreground, the redBackGroundColor view change it's orging.y as you can see in the bellow picture:

[image]

what's the problem ?thanks

Comment: Try code put in the -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIView programatically on method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

     screen=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

//Simple view
    self.customView = [[CustomAlertOKView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, screen.size.width, screen.size.height)];

     [self.view addSubView:customView];

}
```

or

Create a view using storyboard and set the x as 0, y value as 20,width and height based on the screen size

```
@IBOutlet UIView *customView;
```

set the outlet in the storyboard,

Then set the background color of the custom view to redcolor and main view to white color

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i don't understand what the difference between your code and mine ?

Comment: @david no need of adding two views, add only one view with y value as 20 through storyboard, and set the background color based for the base view and the view which u added

Comment: UI changes normally happen in runtime with the help of "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method whenever u make changes on the UI please do that on "viewDidLayoutSubviews method

Comment: thank you for your replay, actually i can't use storyBoard, i build the views programmatically. i will try your solution one minute.

Comment: @david ok , make a try and let me know, i will try to help you out of this issue, Happy coding

Comment: thanks. i removed statusBarWhiteBackGround and just did as i told me, but that doesn't help. also i've override viewDidLayoutSubviews and set the frame there. but that doesn't help also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96562/discussion-between-satheesh-and-david).

Comment: thank you for your help. i was changing the self.view frame, and i don't note that. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: the code in my question also works. yes i accepted your answer. thanks

Comment: @david Wow great keep going :)